# Why is there still padding on the righthand side when using Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to build a small, information website using boostrap just to familiarize myself with it.  Everything was working fine until I realized there is a horizontal scrollbar at the bottom of the screen on all of my pages, and, no matter what I try, there seems to be a small gap ever-present on the righthand side.  I have placed my elements within a DIV using the container-fluid class.  I have overridden the container-fluid class and made the left and right padding 0px, as well as the margins.  So I went back to the most bare-bones skeleton of a page, nothing more than a navbar and a few rows and columns with some red-bordered divs.  I have read several similar questions and tried all of their advice, and nothing is working.  Can anyone tell me what I'm missing here?  Below is the skeletal HTML I'm using and the relevant CSS:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<title>Black Lotus Designs</title>

    <!--Fontawesome Icons-->
    <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/e07888a3dd.js"></script>

    <!--CSS-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./bootstrap-5.0.2-dist/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./Javascript/jquery-ui-1.13.0/jquery-ui.css">
   
    
    <!--JQuery-->
     <script type="text/javascript" src="./Javascript/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
    <!--Jquery UI-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./Javascript/jquery-ui-1.13.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <!--animate.css-->
      
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.1.1/animate.compat.css"/>
   
    <!--Textillate File-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./Javascript/jquery.lettering.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./Javascript/jquery.textillate.js"></script>
    
    <!-- Google Fonts-->
    <!--Spectral-->
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Spectral&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> 

    <!--Oswald-->
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Brawler&family=Caladea&family=Oswald:wght@300&family=Poppins:wght@100;200&family=Roboto:wght@300&family=Spectral&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> 
    <!-- Brawler-->
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Brawler&family=Caladea&family=Poppins:wght@100;200&family=Roboto:wght@300&family=Spectral&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> 
    <!-- -->

   
    <!--bootstrap javascript file-->
    <script src="./bootstrap-5.0.2-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!--custom css file-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./CSS/globals.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./CSS/about.css">
    <!--BOOTSTRAP OVERRIDES-->
    <style>
      
    </style>

    <!--Custom Text Effects File-->
    <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="./Javascript/textEffects.js"></script>-->
</head>

<header>
     <!--Navbar Region-->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="./Images/tabIcon.png"></a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link"  href="./index.html">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="link" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            Services
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown" style="background:black;color:white;">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item ddMenu_Color  active" aria-current="page" href="./services.html">Services</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item ddMenu_Color" href="#">Typographic Elements</a></li>
            <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item ddMenu_Color" href="#">Basic Animations</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="./portfolio.html">Portfolio</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="./about.html">About</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="./blog.html">Blog</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="./gallery.html">Gallery</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="./contact.html">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="d-flex">
        <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<!--End of Navbar Region -->
</header>
 <div class="container-fluid">

    <section>
        <div class="row">
                <div class="col red"></div>
                <div class="col red"></div>
                <div class="col red"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
                <div class="col red"></div>
                <div class="col red"></div>
                <div class="col red"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
                <div class="col red"></div>
                <div class="col red"></div>
                <div class="col red"></div>
        </div>
    </section>

</div>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.red {
    border: 2px solid red;
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
}
.container-fluid {
          padding-left: 0px !important;
          padding-right: 0px !important;
          margin: 0px !important;
      }
```

Thank you in advance....it has been so frustrating, and I assume it is something very simple that I'm overlooking.  It's always the super obvious thing that gets me.  Here's a screen shot---if there's a better solution than hiding stuff, please let me know
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UZEcg.png)

Answer (score 0):

I have probably screwed something else up by doing this, but I tried using overflow:hidden and it worked!  I have the feeling this is going to come back to bite me somewhere...so if anyone knows a better way....isn't the whole point of bootstrap to make things easier?